# I have view controllers in a navigation controller hierarchy, but only want the navigation bar on the first view controller - how do I do this?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller, uistoryboard

I have a main view controller that lists a bunch of items, and when they tap on one of the items it segues them to the next view. However, in the next view, I don't want the navigation bar to be there, I only want it in the first view (I'm using a UIToolBar for the navigation bar, kind of like [in iBooks](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NXe64.jpg)).

How exactly do I go about achieving this? If I remove the main view controller from the navigation controller completely (unembedding, effectively) I can implement the nav bars selectively, but this solution doesn't allow segues, so it's no good.

My other solution was to call `self.navigationController.navigationBarHidden = YES;` in `viewDidAppear` for the second view, but with this, the UIToolBar that I added in my storyboard is pushed under the navigation bar that hasn't been hidden yet, and then when it does get hidden, it disappears and the UIToolBar "falls down", which is a pretty gross effect to the user.

What would be the best way to go about getting this effect?

Answer (score 1):

The best way to do that is the following. In you `viewWillAppear:` in the first (rootViewController) of your UINavigationController, you set:

```
-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
    [self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:NO animated:animated];
}
```

and then in you `viewWillDisappear`, you the the opposite:

```
-(void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillDisappear:animated];
    [self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:YES animated:animated];
}
```

This way should work without nothing 'ugly' happening to the user.

Comment: Wait, the black bar is appearing in the rootViewController? If so, It should be there according to your question, no? You can try to use the same methods I posted above, but inverted, in the other view controllers pushed... Please accept/upvote answer if it helped solving your problem.

Comment: I guess it makes sense conceptually to be there, but visually it doesn't look great, what would be the best way to not have such a visual eyesore? I'd prefer the nav bar to be there until it gets to the next view, where it isn't.

Comment: Also, the previous bar doesn't completely disappear. When I tap back with this method it reappears for a second. http://i.imgur.com/E38k7fV.png

Comment: I deleted first comment as it was misleading, but yes, the black bar is indeed an issue that causes a great eyesore: http://i.imgur.com/h4lR6CA.png